# Menu items in data bound menu displaying oddly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code in my XAML:

```
            <Menu x:Name="MainMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Padding="0,3">
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text}" Icon="{Binding Icon}" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}" Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </MenuItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>
```

I then bind the ItemsSource property and populate it with my menu items from plugins.

Not that I believe it is relevant, here is some of the code behind:

```
MainMenu.ItemsSource = Global.MainMenu; //You can assume the Global class is exactly what it looks like, a shared class holding many of the programs settings and stores.

ApplicationMenuItem mappingMenu = new ApplicationMenuItem();
mappingMenu.Text = "Edit Mapping";
mappingMenu.Clicked += (se, ev) => { MainFrame.Navigate(new Pages.DeviceMapping()); };
Global.MainMenu.Add(mappingMenu);
```

-

```
    public class ApplicationMenuItem
{
    public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationMenuItem> Items { get; set; }
    public EventHandler Clicked {get;set;}
    public void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clicked!=null)
            Clicked(this, e);
    }
    private ICommand _ClickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ClickCommand == null)
            {
                _ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Click(this, EventArgs.Empty));
            }
            return _ClickCommand;
        }
    }
    public ApplicationMenuItem(string Text)
    {
        this.Text = Text;
        Items = new List<ApplicationMenuItem>();
    }
    public ApplicationMenuItem()
    {
        Items = new List<ApplicationMenuItem>();
    }

}
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameters)
    {
        _execute(parameters);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

The issue is the items are not displaying in the way I would expect, they appear to be much wider than normal `MenuItem`'s that are inside `Menu` controls and appear to be wrapped inside another control causing a double border.

[image]

Where did I go wrong, am I not using the binding for menu's properly?

Comment: It seems like you have menuitem inside menuitem. How do you will the menu items source?

Comment: @Liero huh? I do? where?

Comment: Because menu will create menuitems for you. ItemTemplate is just template for menuitems' content

Comment: @Liero lemme take a look at that, if that is it ill close this down.

Comment: @Liero thats looks better, but having issues adopting my event handler that usually utilizes the `command` parameter of the `MenuItem` to bind a anonymous function as the result of a click.

Comment: You can use ItemContainerStyle property to set the command.

Comment: @Liero not having much luck finding a example for this case, most cases I see involve binding sub menu items to a singular menu item rather than root menu items to a menu

Comment: nevermind, solution was right in my face, was just thrown by the fact that the IDE had the option to convert the itemContainerStyle to a local value was greyed out, manually writing the code worked just fine though, thank you. Out of curiosity, am I going about this in the right manner?